# Can anybody name this theorem that deals with remainders of power series in connection with radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to find out more and especially get a better idea about the background of a theorem that goes as follows:

$\underline{\text{Theorem}}$

If we have a radius of convergence $R>0$ of a series $$A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$,

then for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and for every $0<r<R$ there is a number $c=c_{N+1}(r)$ such that $$|A(z) - \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_nz^n|\leq c|z|^{N+1}$$ for all z with $|z|\leq r$.

So if anybody might have a comprehensible reference or an explanation were this is "coming from", it would be very helpful.

Comment: You have$$\left|A(z)-\sum_{n=0}^Na_nz^n\right|\le\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty|a_n||z|^n = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_{k+N+1}||z|^k\right)|z|^{N+1}.$$Can you now argue that the stuff in parentheses is bounded inside the circle with radius $r$?

Comment: Do you mean since $|z| < r$, and $r<1$, and since $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{k+N+1}|z|^k$$ will only ever reach parts of $A(z)$, the stuff in parentheses must be smaller than r? Which would mean that the remainder of the approximation of the series approximated by taking a series from $n = 0$ until $n=N$ is bounded by r?

Comment: The answer to your question is no. The thing in parentheses is again a power series (in $|z|$). It has a radius of convegence. What is this radius?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought parentheses meant the bars that indicate absolute values (translation problem, my fault), I'll think about it again.